# Proving quotient of $\mathcal{O}_K $ with ideal $I$ is finite.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, quotient-group, algebraic-integers

I need help showing the following
:
Suppose $K$ is a number field of degree $n$ and $\mathfrak{a} $ is a non-zero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K $.
Then $\mathfrak{a} $ as an additive finitely generated abelian subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K^+ $ has rank $n$.

**Here is what I know**

$\mathcal{O}_K$ Is a finitely generated abelian group of rank $n$. I know that $\mathcal{O}_K /I $ is a finite group.
Now I have some feeling that if $I$ has rank $m<n $ then $(I,+) \cong \mathbb{Z}^m $ and this somehow means that the quotient is infinite as $\mathcal{O}_K^+ \cong \mathbb{Z}^n $ but don’t know how to precisely pin this down.

Comment: Your title and body do not seem to match. Are you asking why the quotient is finite or why the group is free abelian of rank $n$ when already knowing that quotient is finite?

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of localization and/or tensor products?

Comment: You’re right the title doesn’t match what I say. I mean, given that the quotient is finite that the rank is $n$

Comment: @Ben - you find a proof in Neukirch, "Algebraic number theory" Prop.2.10: $\mathfrak{a} \cong \mathbb{Z}\{e_1,..,e_n\}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Here is what I know: $O_K$ is a finitely generated abelian group of rank n. I know that $O_K/I$ is a finite group. Now I have some feeling that if $I$ has rank $m<n$ then $(I,+)≅Z^m$ and this somehow means that the quotient is infinite as $O^+_K≅Z^n$ but don’t know how to precisely pin this down."

**Answer:** You find a proof in Neukirch "Algebraic number theory", Proposition 2.10 (page 12).